# Doubt about the symbology in mathematics in the law of internal composition.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

One question , in Spanish when you look for the law of internal composition in wikipedia has a good article about this however I have doubts of the symbology since the operators shown I do not understand them , any idea how to explain them? the only way I understand is that they are as operators.
In quantum quantum operators express operations, is it the same?

https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/7010dc213919c906514abc67a0eb5835e87edac8

Comment: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ley_de_composici%C3%B3n#:~:text=La%20ley%20de%20composici%C3%B3n%20es%20interna%20si%20la%20aplicaci%C3%B3n%20que,ley%20de%20composici%C3%B3n%20es%20externa.

Comment: Here is the complete link in case you want to have the article

Comment: The symbols are arbitrary. What is important is that whatever symbol we use represents an operation of pairs of elements of $A$ that get mapped to $A$. They given an example where the product computes the average of two elements. The idea is not to define a specific symbol but to define what is meant by a law of internal composition as opposed to a law of external composition. By convention, they are using two different sets of symbols to represent the different compositions.